# Time-based rotation of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which should rotate through the values of a constant (**const rotation**). It should continuously running and starting from a certain value and starting date (**const known**)

The next value in the list should always appear after 30 minutes with one exception: if the "id" of the value is "193234" (Eldoren) the next value should always appear after 60 minutes (not 30 minutes).

The problem is that this exception only works for the first appeareance of the id "193234", not for later ones:

**Output:**

```
01:00 Skag
01:30 Pfliep
02:00 Magmaton
02:30 Eldoren // 1 hour until the next value, which is correct
03:30 Skag
04:00 Pfliep
04:30 Magmaton
05:00 Eldoren // should be 1 hour until the next value, too
05:30 Skag // so start should be at 06:00
```

This is my script and the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0tm7nsh/):

```
 $(function () {
          if ($("[id^=test]").length) {
            function addHours(date, hours) {
              var copy = new Date(date);
              copy.setTime(copy.getTime() + hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
              return copy;
            }
    
            function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
              return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes * 60000);
            }
    
            function next(value) {
              return {
                index: (value.index + 1) % rotation.length,
                date: addHours(value.date, 0.5),
              };
            }
    
            const known = { id: 193210, ts: "2023-06-20T17:30:00" };
            const rotation = [
              { id: 193210, name: "Pfliep " },
              { id: 186827, name: "Magmaton" },
              { id: 193234, name: "Eldoren" },
              { id: 193149, name: "Skag" },
            ];
    
            const now33 = new Date();
            const now2 = addHours(now33, 10);
            const now3 = addHours(now33, -0);
            const end = addHours(now33, rotation.length * 2);
    
            var cur = {
              index: rotation.findIndex((li) => li.id == known.id),
              date: Date.parse(known.ts),
            };
    
            while (cur.date < now3) {
              cur = next(cur);
            }
    
            const out = document.getElementById("test");
    
            let increaseMinutes = 0;
    
            while (cur.date < end && cur.date < now2 && cur.date > now3) {
              const li = document.createElement("li");
              li.className = "test";
    
              var link = document.createElement("a");
              link.textContent = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
              link.href = "dadada";
              link.class = "dadada";
    
              li.innerText = `${rotation[cur.index].name} (${cur.date.toLocaleString()})`;
    
              var id = `${rotation[cur.index].id}`;
              var title2 = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
              var link = "https://de.wowhead.com/npc=";
              var ClassName = "weeklytext";
              var ClassName2 = "weeklytext2";
              var ClassName3 = "peinigertime";
    
              var options = { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };
    
              var date33 = `${addMinutes(cur.date, increaseMinutes).toLocaleString("en-GB", options)}`;
    
              if (id == 193234) {
                increaseMinutes = 30;
              } else if (increaseMinutes > 0) {
                increaseMinutes += 0;
              }
    
              $(
                '<li class="' +
                  ClassName2 +
                  '"><div class="' +
                  ClassName3 +
                  '"> ' +
                  date33 +
                  '</div> <a class="' +
                  ClassName +
                  '" href="' +
                  link +
                  +id +
                  '">' +
                  title2 +
                  "</a></li>"
              ).appendTo(out);
              cur = next(cur);
            }
          }
        });
```